# How to combine inner list into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists. I am trying to combine the inner list of characters into one string.

For example:

```
values = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
newValues =['abc', 'def', 'ghe']
```

This is what I have but it's not working. I can't figure out how to get the syntax to work. :/

```
values = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

for i in values:
    print(" ".join(values[i]))
```

Comment: `i` isn't a index, it's the value itself. so you just needed `print(" ".join(i))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right lines, you can either use a list comprehension like:

```
new_values = ["".join(sub_list) for sub_list in values]
```

Or a for loop:

```
new_values = []
for sub_list in values:
    new_values.append("".join(sub_list))
```

Both output:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

A couple of notes about your code:
Your loop won't work as you've written it as `for i in values` means that every value of `i` will contain a sub list, not an index to it, so to print it out as you have in your example, you would either need to do:

```
for i in range(len(values)):  # Here, i will contain the index values
    print("".join(values[i]))
```

or

```
for i in values:  # Here, i will contain the sub_list
    print("".join(i))
```

Finally, if you follow the [PEP-8](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/) Python coding standards, you shouldn't use camelCase for variable names, so `newValues` should be `new_values`

Answer (score 0):

The `.join` hints into the right direction, but i is already the sub-list so you can do the following:

```
result = ["".join(i) for i in values] 
print(result)
```